# Using an Array list to navigate screens Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have created a program to make a list where the user types in a a name and presses the add class button and it is added to the list. Although is it possible to use items in that list to navigate to a new screen.

As in the user inputs Math, then the user presses "math" and it will take them to a new screen? Or can this only be done by buttons? Here is my code:

```
public class toclass extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.classes);

        ListView myClassView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myClassView);
        final EditText classEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.classEditText);
        final ArrayList<String> noteList = new ArrayList<String>();
        final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;

        aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>      (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,noteList);

        myClassView.setAdapter(aa);

        Button btnAddClass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddClass);


        btnAddClass.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                noteList.add(0, classEditText.getText().toString());
                aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                classEditText.setText("");

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: As I understand you right you are searching for a [click listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) of your `ListView`. So it is like `myClassView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){...});`

Answer (score 0):

On your list view, use setOnItemClickListener